# Angular: Dragging the scrollbar in Firefox doesn't show the now-visible content until the primary mouse key is no longer pressed

Tags: css, angular, firefox, scrollbar

I have a sidebar which is filled with content using a *ngFor directive. It can happen that the content is taller than the screen size, so the sidebar has a scrollbar.

In Firefox dragging the scrollbar moves the content in the sidebar correctly, however the now visible lower (or upper) part of the sidebar content is only shown when I no longer click the mouse button. When I depress the primary mouse button the content pops up correctly. This doesn't happen in Chrome.

When I scroll using the mouse wheel the newly visible content also takes a couple of seconds to pop up.

I am using Angular Version 16 and Firefox 118.0.2

EDIT:
The container which holds the ngFor directive has the following Angular Animation:

```js
trigger('slideInOutHorizontal', [
      transition(':enter', [style({ width: 0 }), animate('250ms ease-in-out')]),
      transition(':leave', [animate('250ms ease-in-out', style({ width: 0 }))]),
    ]),
```

During further research I've found a bunch of problems with Angular animations and firefox, could this be the issue?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.